# 500 Internal Server Error for sub domain using htaccess in SilverStripe 3.1

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain, silverstripe, internal-server-error

I am getting a 500 server error for a sub domain. It was working perfectly before installing SilverStripe 3. Is there any modification needed in the default `.htaccess` created by SilverStripe installation?

Comment: Take a look at your log files ;) there should be an error.

Comment: @Stony It's seems like SS default htaccess file creating issue to access it. What modification I can do in it?

Comment: Checking the logs for the reason and posting it here should help us helping you :) There shouldn't be any problem with subdomains in `.htaccess`. We have all our dev sites running in subdomains with zero problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks every one for their support, but I follow different method.
I have created sub domain from cpanel, but selected same root folder instead of creating new directory.
I got the help from here.
https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/domain-redirecting-to-cgi-sys-defaultwebpage-cgi.139597/page-3#post-656642

Answer (score 5):

This answer makes a few assumptions from your question.

These assumptions are

- Your SilverStripe website is the root website (e.g. http://www.example.com)
- Your SilverStripe code is in the root web directory (e.g. `/public_html`)
- You sub-domain code is in a sub-folder of the root web directory (e.g. `/public_html/sub`

The problem that can occur in the above situation is the sub-domain may use the `/public_html/.htaccess` file and use its `mod_rewrite` rules.

To solve this we can create a `.htaccess` file in the sub-domain (`/public_html/sub/.htaccess`) with the following code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
</IfModule>
```

This will tell the server to not use the `mod_rewrite` rules or base of the root `.htaccess` file.

An alternative solution could be to not place sub-domain code in a sub-folder of the root web directory. You can create a folder on the root level such as `/sub` and have your sub-domain point to there.